# In onKeyup AJAX call not working first time or back pressing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
var d=0;
    function checkhrsforDate(){
        var date=$('#approveapplieddate').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "datelogic.php",
            type: "post",
            data:'date='+date,
            cache: false,
            success:function(htmlData){
                if(htmlData=='')
                {
                    d=0;
                }
                else{
                    d=htmlData;
                }
                return d;
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#approveappliedhrs").onkeyup(function (e) {
                var approvedate=$('#approvedate').val();
                var approveapplieddate=$('#approveapplieddate').val();
                appliedhrs=$("#appliedhrs").val();
                hrs=parseInt($(this).val());
                if($(this).val().length==1){
                    checkhrsforDate();
            }
        });
    });
```

First time it showing d value as 0 and next key press it's working
    fine. But my textbox allows only one value. is it possible to call AJAX call in keyup event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onkeyup` is a javascript event,

**CORRECTION**

```
function checkhrsforDate(){
var d = 0;
var date = $('#approveapplieddate').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "datelogic.php",
    type: "post",
    data:{date: date},
    cache: false,
    success:function(htmlData){
        if(htmlData=='')
        {
            d = 0;
        }
        else{
            d = htmlData;
        }
        return d;
    }
});
}
$("#approveappliedhrs").keyup(function(e) {
var approvedate = $('#approvedate').val();
var approveapplieddate = $('#approveapplieddate').val();
appliedhrs = $("#appliedhrs").val();
hrs = parseInt($(this).val());
if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
    checkhrsforDate();
}
});
```

value of d will depend upon what you return. If it is json string then you can check like `if(htmlData=='')`.

For better answer paste your `ajax` response

Comment: sarry, its not working.I changed onkeyup to keyup but it showing 0 only in first ajax call

Comment: Answer updated. Check you PHP page too for proper response.